# Turn Off Whole Line Copy in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to disable the function in Visual Studio Code where if you don't have a selection highlighted, ctrl+c copies the entire line.  I have never tried to do this on purpose, but I am always doing it accidentally when I hit ctrl+c instead of ctrl+v.

Here's what I have tried, which seems like it should work:

Under File->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts, there is the default setting:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+c", "command":  "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
                   "when": "editorTextFocus" },
```

I have attempted to change this, so that it only copies when something is selected, by placing the following in my keybindings.json file:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+c",  "command": "-editor.action.clipboardCopyAction"},
{ "key": "ctrl+c",  "command": "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
                    "when": "editorHasSelection" }
```

I think this should clear the previous binding before re-binding the copy action to only function when something is actually selected.  HOWEVER, it doesn't work.  The editor still copies a whole line when nothing is selected.  If I only have the first line in there, it successfully removes the binding completely, so I know it's doing something, but the "when" tag doesn't seem to be functioning the way it should.

Is there any way to get the editor to do what I want?

Comment: This appears to be a known issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11112

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In Settings enter the following line:

```
"editor.emptySelectionClipboard": false
```

That should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you!  You are a life saver.

Comment: You're very welcome. I hate that vanishing copy buffer as well.

Comment: THANK YOU - the amount of times I've done this on accident is infuriating!

Comment: Through a horrible twist of fate, `CTRL+x` is Emacs for do something useful. The number of lines I have accidentally deleted while trying to save my file in VS code is horrendous. This tip is amazing, thank you so much. I would +250 again if I could.

Answer (score 4):

Because this comes up on Google as a popular answer...

FYI this is also now a setting in the Settings GUI, search the settings for "empty selection" and it'll narrow it down. Untick to disable and praise your chosen deity.

Answer (score 2):

Even after applying the `"editor.emptySelectionClipboard": false` setting the problem would persist. I had to remove/edit the project specific settings in the `.vscode/` folder within the project folder.