# Disable cutting without selection in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I type `Ctrl + x` in vscode without active selection, it will cut the current line. Is there a way to disable that? It's too close to `Ctrl + z` for me and I only ever do it accidentally.

Comment: A quick search will take you to: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings which has what you need. You can change all keybindings under "File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts. (Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts on macOS)"

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322024/turn-off-whole-line-copy-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: @sorifiend I know the keyboard shortcuts dialog but there I can only entirely disable the `ctrl+x` shortcut, which is not what I want.

Comment: @AshokKumarThangaraj ahh yes that works, thanks! and I also found another apparent solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67286304/can-you-disable-the-cut-line-function-of-cut-shortcut-ctrlx-in-vscode) that I must have missed when googling earlier earlier. So I guess this question is officially a duplicate!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turn Off Whole Line Copy in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322024/turn-off-whole-line-copy-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: I rejected the "possible duplicate" dialogue since in my opinion it should be a duplicate of the question I linked in my comment rather than the one Ashok linked